# How to write a BT node that subscribe a topic (navigation2)

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to write a BT node that recieve state of a bumper.

But my code can not catch messages of a bumper.

How can I write a BT Node that works properly with subscription?

Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include <rclcpp/qos.hpp>
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>

#include "behaviortree_cpp_v3/condition_node.h"
#include "gazebo_msgs/msg/contacts_state.hpp"
#include "geometry_msgs/msg/pose_stamped.hpp"

namespace nav2_behavior_tree {

class BumperCollisionCondition : public BT::ConditionNode {
  public:
    BumperCollisionCondition(const std::string &condition_name, const BT::NodeConfiguration &conf);

    BumperCollisionCondition() = delete;

    BT::NodeStatus tick() override;

    static BT::PortsList providedPorts() {
        return {};
    }

  private:
    rclcpp::Subscription<gazebo_msgs::msg::ContactsState>::SharedPtr contact_state_;
    rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node_;
    rclcpp::Time lasttime_;
};

} // namespace nav2_behavior_tree

namespace nav2_behavior_tree {

BumperCollisionCondition::BumperCollisionCondition(
    const std::string &condition_name,
    const BT::NodeConfiguration &conf)
    : BT::ConditionNode(condition_name, conf) {
  node_ = config().blackboard->get<rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr>("node");
  auto qos = rclcpp::SystemDefaultsQoS();
  qos.best_effort();
  contact_state_ = node_->create_subscription<gazebo_msgs::msg::ContactsState>(
    "bumper_front",
    qos,
    [this](const gazebo_msgs::msg::ContactsState::SharedPtr msg) -> void {
      RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "TEST"); // "TEST" never print.
      auto states = msg->states;
      lasttime_ = rclcpp::Time(msg->header.stamp);
    });
}

BT::NodeStatus BumperCollisionCondition::tick() {
    RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "test %d", lasttime_.nanoseconds()); // lasttime_ never update.
    return BT::NodeStatus::FAILURE;
}

} // namespace nav2_behavior_tree

#include "behaviortree_cpp_v3/bt_factory.h"
BT_REGISTER_NODES(factory) {
    factory.registerNodeType<nav2_behavior_tree::BumperCollisionCondition>("BumperCollision");
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371973/how-to-write-a-bt-node-that-subscribe-a-topic-(navigation2)./) by [Kazunari Tanaka](https://answers.ros.org/users/70222/kazunari-tanaka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2021-02-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vinny](https://answers.ros.org/users/52902/vinny/) on 2021-02-17**:
while you provided the code for the node, can you provide the overall tree you are trying to use this  BT node in?  I wonder if this condition node is ever being checked.

I want to ask to make sure that the condition has an appropriate parent, for example `ReactiveFallback`
[Fallback Nodes](https://www.behaviortree.dev/fallbacknode/)

**Comment by [Kazunari Tanaka](https://answers.ros.org/users/70222/kazunari-tanaka/) on 2021-02-17**:
Thank you your response!
My bt is here.

```
<root main_tree_to_execute="MainTree">
    <BehaviorTree ID="MainTree">
      <RetryUntilSuccesful num_attempts="-1">
        <BumperCollision/>
      </RetryUntilSuccesful>
    </BehaviorTree>
</root>
```

I observed that tick method is called in every frame.

**Comment by [Kazunari Tanaka](https://answers.ros.org/users/70222/kazunari-tanaka/) on 2021-02-17**:
I changed the bt tree to following. Then the callback function was called. I seem that the point is lifetime of BT node. correct?

```
<root main_tree_to_execute="MainTree">
    <BehaviorTree ID="MainTree">
      <ReactiveFallback name="BumperFallback">
        <BumperCollision/>
        <Wait wait_duration="20000"/>
      </ReactiveFallback>
    </BehaviorTree>
</root>
```

**Comment by [vinny](https://answers.ros.org/users/52902/vinny/) on 2021-02-18**:
Yeah, I think simply ticking the tree like you did in the `RetryUntilSuccessful` does not allow the node to enter  to the callback where as `ReactiveFallback` will allow it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using a `ReactiveFallback` parent node rather than `RetryUntilSuccessful` allowed the custom condition node to work.

```
<root main_tree_to_execute="MainTree">
<BehaviorTree ID="MainTree">
  <ReactiveFallback name="BumperFallback">
    <BumperCollision/>
    <Wait wait_duration="20000"/>
  </ReactiveFallback>
</BehaviorTree>
```

---

Originally posted by [vinny](https://answers.ros.org/users/52902/vinny/) with karma: 291 on 2021-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2